# Failed to bind to system using LDAP

Tags: php, ldap, bind

I have a system and want to connect it to AD using LDAP. I try to test the connection first but it is a fail. It only print out '1' which means the code only run until **(sizeof($_POST) > 0**. What did I forgot to code ? I need to know where is lacking in my coding. Hope someone can help me out.

This is my full code for the LDAP.php : '

```
<?php


if (sizeof($_POST) > 0) {
echo "1";
if($ds = @ldap_connect('10.5.10.540', '389')) {
    $username = $_POST["user_id"] . "@mydomain.local";
    echo "2";
    if ($status=@ldap_bind($ds,  $username,$_POST["user_password"])) {
        echo "3";
        @ldap_unbind($ds);
        echo "Success.";
    }
}
echo "3";
@ldap_unbind($ds);
}


?>
<html>
<body>
<form action = "ldapts2.php" method="post">
Username: <input type="text" name="user_id" >
Password: <input type="password" name="user_password" >

<input type="submit" value = "Login">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by that ?

Comment: never mind, i was confusing two questions ...

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I already configure the problem ! The thing is, I just only forgot to copy libsasl.dll in php folder. After I paste the file, the code can function successfully. 
Now I'll proceed to the real LDAP authentication !